# MySql keep loosing tablespace id for random tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0

In one of our databases we are seeing more and more frequent errors where the table space id of an innodb file is lost.

We are running mysql 8.0.31.

The error message in the log file is:

```
[ERROR] [MY-012095] [InnoDB] [FATAL] Tablespace id is 20331 in the data dictionary but in file ./<databasename>/<table_name>#p#p20231012.ibd it is 0!
```

This has happened several times, and the frequency of this error seems to increase, and it is not the same table every time.

We are able to get the database server up and running again using innodb_force_recovery=3, but that does not fix the issue, and the error is still present if trying to go back to innodb_force_recovery=0.

We have not found any good way of resolving this issue other than dropping the table and restoring it from backup. Which takes a while considering most of our tables are several GB's.

Does anybody know why this happens?
Any easier way to resolve this other than restoring from backup? (Yes, we have tried repair tools etc found through other questions about the same, but with no success)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to "move" tables around by moving `.ibd` files on the filesystem?